# Azure Speech SDK callback not working for continuous Speech Recognition

Tags: fastapi

Building a realtime continuous chat service with websocket , I dont see text sent back from recognized_callback although the prints are showing up in console.Its a FASTAPI application

The first part of code

```
async def process_stream(stream,data,speech_recognizer,websocket):


    def recognized_callback(evt):
        recognized_text = evt.result.text
        print("I am in websocket callback : " + str(recognized_text)+" "+str(websocket))

        async def send_data():
            await websocket.send_text(recognized_text)

        asyncio.gather(send_data())


    # The number of bytes to push per buffer
    n_bytes = 4096
    data = io.BytesIO(data)

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_callback)

    # Start pushing data until all data has been read from the file
    try:
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
        while True:

            frames = data.read(n_bytes // 2)
            print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
            if not frames:
                speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
                break
            stream.write(frames)

            await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
    finally:
        stream.close()

@app.websocket("/asr/en")
async def root(websocket:WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            # Receive audio data from the client
            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            break

        await process_stream(stream,data,speech_recognizer,websocket)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: This will be duplicate question, you have already posted the same question.